# unexpected result when using phangorn::simSeq()

Tags: r

I am using phangorn::simSeq()

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/phangorn/versions/2.4.0/topics/simSeq

and I use type = "DNA" as parameter.

In the result message I get "The states are a c g t" (which is what I expect, but then when I see the result is:
[image]

I expect to see A,C,T,G as results not 1,2,3,4... how can I make A,C,T,G appear instead of 1,2,3,4... I thought I got that by specifying the parameter `type="DNA"`

Answer (score 0):

`simSeq` returns a `phyDat` object. You can transform this object to a character matrix using `as.character` or export it using `write.phyDat`.

```
> library(phangorn)
> tree <- rcoal(5)
> dat <- simSeq(tree, l=10)
> as.character(dat)
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
t2 "t"  "g"  "c"  "c"  "t"  "g"  "a"  "g"  "t"  "a"  
t5 "g"  "t"  "c"  "t"  "t"  "t"  "t"  "g"  "c"  "g"  
t1 "g"  "t"  "c"  "t"  "t"  "t"  "t"  "g"  "c"  "g"  
t3 "g"  "a"  "g"  "c"  "t"  "t"  "t"  "c"  "g"  "g"  
t4 "g"  "g"  "g"  "g"  "t"  "a"  "a"  "g"  "g"  "g"
```